# Google Sheets Querying

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am working on creating some automated sheets and have a question. To start, I have data that I upload to a master sheet and then query that data to another sheet titled Query based on whether or not a column is equal to "True". (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJZx0.png)

This now pulls all data that has column H = "TRUE" from the original master sheet into a sheet titled Query.. Multiple rows may have the same value in column A in this query sheet.

I then have another sheet titled Working that provides a list of the Unique Values from Column A in the Query sheet. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNNf6.png)

My question is, based off of the unique values in the working sheet, how can I query the original master sheet to provide all rows associated with the unique values? For example, if the some of the unique values end up as "Apple", "Banana" and "Orange", how can I retrieve any rows from the original master sheet that has those values in column A. The unique values list will be around 300 on a daily basis and manually typing in each value seems a bit absurd! Thanks for the help!

I tried querying single values which works fine but for a list of 300+ unique values, there has to be an easier way to query a range of values.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is with a helper cell. Something I like to use is dropdown lists.
For example, assume this is your data:
[image]

Here is your working sheet with the unique values:
[image]

In another sheet, create a dropdown list using a range of values, and point it to your unique list:
[image]

Then, use a query formula to pull from the master sheet where column A is equal to the dropdown value:
`=QUERY(query!A2:B, "SELECT * WHERE A = '"&B1&"'")`
[image]

This can be altered to however you need it to work, but I believe this idea is what you might be looking for. The dropdown will adjust itself to fit the unique list as it changes.